# Generating a larger group using automorphism

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

I.N. Herstein says,

> Generally, if $G$ is a group, $T$ an automorphism of order $r$ of $G$ which is not an inner automorphism, pick a symbol $x$ and consider all elements $x^ig$, $i=0,+1,+2,...-1,-2..,$ $g \in G$ subject to $x^ig=x^{i'}g'$ if and only if $i=i'mod r, g=g'$ and $x^{-1}g^ix=gT^i$ for all $i$. This way we obtain a larger group $\{G,T\}$...

This is the first time I am studying group theory in particular and abstract algebra so formally in general.

Naturally, even though I have followed the book closely up until this point so that I am able to understand what the author says, I do not feel satisfied at all.

Is there a more inisghtful/less adhoc/more natural way of understanding how automorphisms of a group enable creation of larger groups?

Edit: Note I am particularly asking for automorphisms which are not inner and for which the above quoted construction is used. The case of inner automorphism (and how the group created is huge!) is something (I think) I understand.

Comment: This construction is an example of a more general construction known as the *semidirect product*, which is very important in group theory. Here we are taking the semidirect product of $G$ with a cyclic group of order $r$ that acts on $G$ as the auomorphism $T$.

Comment: You went from asking multiple related things about the construction to asking something high level to the point of being vague, e.g. a "more natural way of understanding".  A more focused Question would take one of your original "asks" and drilling down on that query.  It is natural to wonder why the fact that $T$ is not an inner automorphism is important (hint: it is related to getting a strictly bigger group).  The best way to "feel satisfied" is to work with the material until you can explain it to someone else.

Comment: @hardmath I clearly understand how inner automorphisms generate larger groups and why they are not preferred. The order is $n!$ if $G$ is $n$. I guess I was not able to put clearly my question across. The manipulation with inner automorphism to generate a larger group seemed *natural* as it hinged on the closure property in  away that was not dense.

Comment: @harmath On the other hand, I.N Herstein pulls out the above (for non-inner automorphism/the one quoted in the question) construction out of a hat. As such it felt like a discontinuity and therefore I hope to understand it in a more natural/ more motivated way. Why does the construction work? And what was the insight on which this construction hinges or relies on? is basically what I want to know.

Comment: As Derek Holt said already, it is a semidirect product $C_r \ltimes G$. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product for more background. By the way there is nothing wrong with using an inner automorphism, but often (not always) the group will be isomorphic to the direct product $C_r \times G$.